Graph search maximizing vertex features while minimizings
Problem: given a graph G of edges E and nodes N, each node has a weight c, while each edge has a weight as length. Given the edge, find a subgraph to connect nodes such that the sum of distance is smaller than the given threshold and the sum of x is maximized.
Note: the graph is big and could contain ~2000 nodes and ~3000 edges
I used networkx in python to create a graph and then used use ChatGPT to help me solve this problem. It suggested a dfs approach. The code is given below. It works for a small graph but fails with memory error when I run on my original graph (~2000 nodes and ~3000 edges)
G = nx.Graph()

# Add nodes with x values
nodes_x = {0:10, 1: 20, 2: 60, 3: 20, 4: 60, 5: 5, 6:50, 7:80, 8:100, 9:50, 10:2, 11:5}
for node, x_value in nodes_x.items():
    G.add_node(node, population=x_value)

# Add edges with distances
edges_d = {
            (0,1):100,
            (1,2):500, (2,3):400, (1,3):100,
            (3,10):40, (10,8):40, (8,9):70,
            (6,9):200, (3,6):50, (5,6):100, (4,5):50, (7,4):200, (1,7):150, (4,11):20}
for (u, v), dist in edges_d.items():
    G.add_edge(u, v, length=dist)

adj = nx.to_numpy_array(G)

from math import inf

max_dist = 500  
points = nodes_x  

n = len(G.nodes)  
total_points = sum(points.values())  

dp = [[-inf for _ in range(total_points + 1)] for _ in range(n)]
path = [["" for _ in range(total_points + 1)] for _ in range(n)]

def dfs(current_node, points_collected, current_distance, visited, current_path):
    global max_points, best_path

    if current_distance <= max_dist and points_collected > max_points:
        max_points = points_collected
        best_path = current_path[:] 

    for neighbor in G.neighbors(current_node):
        if not visited[neighbor]: 
            visited[neighbor] = True
            weight = G[current_node][neighbor].get('length', inf)
            new_points = points_collected + points[neighbor]
            current_path.append(neighbor)  
            dfs(neighbor, new_points, current_distance + weight, visited, current_path)
            visited[neighbor] = False
            current_path.pop()  

max_points = 0
best_path = ""

for start_vertex in range(n):
    visited = [False] * n  
    visited[start_vertex] = True  
    current_path = [start_vertex] 
    dfs(start_vertex, points[start_vertex], 0, visited, current_path)

print("Max Points:", max_points)
print("Best Path:", " -> ".join(map(str, best_path)))


Did you notice that the dfs method is recursive?  No wonder you run out of memory.  Google ( not Chatgpt!!!!!!!!!! ) non recursive DFS implementation.

ChatGPT tends to generally produce bogus or inefficient codes for non trivial ones. You should really avoid this for developing applications. It is only fine for prototypes (so you do not care much about the result, the stability and the performance of the application).

By the way, for large graphs, it is better not to use Python for expensive computing parts (you can still use Python for a glue code but the expensive parts should be written in a native language so to reduce both the execution time and memory usage). This is how most fast Python modules works, including Numpy and Scipy for example. Thousands of node is not so big though (at least for a DFS). Using a native language does not fix the stack overflow issue which should be addressed anyway (as pointed out by ravenspoint).

I wouldn't be surprised if this constrained optimization problem is NP-Complete, in which case trying to do it for a graph with 2000 nodes is going to take a WHILE (unless the graph happens to have some other properties you can take advantage of). Also, it seems like your dfs function doesn't immediately backtrack if the current path goes over max_dist, and I think adding that could cut down your runtime significantly.

"sum of x is maximized" - there is no x mentioned earlier
